# Ansible assign random number and increase the retry attempts

Tags: random, ansible

I am trying to assign a random number between 7000 and 7005 to a variable which is not present in a list.
the list has 7000, 7001, 7004 and 7002.

```
- name: Set fact 
  set_fact:
    val: "{{ 7004 | random(start=7000) }}"
  until: val not in list
```

The above playbook tried to assign 3 times and failed. It did not assign the value 7003.

```
TASK [xxx] ******************************
task path: /tmp/awx_164677__l9__xmu/project/roles/xxxxx/tasks/main.yml:26
FAILED - RETRYING: Set fact  (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set fact  (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Set fact  (1 retries left).
fatal: [xxxprod]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"val": "7000"}, "attempts": 3, "changed": false}
```

How to increase the retry value from 3 to some other value?

Note: the above list was updated by this playbook, only the last value did not get updated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`retries` playbook keyword can be used to specify the number of retries before giving up in a `until` loop. This setting is only used in combination with `until` Keyword.

```
- name: Set fact 
  set_fact:
    val: "{{ 7004 | random(start=7000) }}"
  until: val not in list
  retries: 5
```

Here is the refereance for you to look more [Retries Playbook Keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-retries)

Answer (score 0):

Make the random choice from the missing items only. The playbook below solves the general problem of randomly completing a sequence

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vals: [7000, 7003]
    vals_all: [7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004]
    vals_missing: "{{ vals_all|difference(vals)|length }}"
    
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        vals2: "{{ vals }}"
    - set_fact:
        vals2: "{{ vals2 + [vals_all|difference(vals2)|random] }}"
      with_sequence: end="{{ vals_missing }}"
    - debug:
        var: vals2
```

gives

```yaml
  vals2:
  - 7000
  - 7003
  - 7002
  - 7001
  - 7004
```

---

If you want to iterate the random generation of the missing items the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vals: [7000, 7003]
    vals_all: [7000, 7001, 7002, 7003, 7004]
    vals_missing: "{{ vals_all|difference(vals)|length }}"
    
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        vals2: "{{ vals }}"
    - debug:
        var: val
      with_sequence: end="{{ vals_missing }}"
      vars:
        val: "{{ [vals_all|difference(vals2)|random] }}"
        vals2: "{{ vals2 + [vals] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: '1'
  val:
  - 7002
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: '2'
  val:
  - 7004
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: '3'
  val:
  - 7001
```

Change the variable `vals: [7000, 7001, 7004, 7002]` to solve your problem. (But, it's trivial because only a single item is missing.)